# Facebook Flux todomvc tutorial - cant start up a simple node http-server because of package.json file

Tags: facebook, npm, reactjs-flux, httpserver, package.json

Warning: This question is from a noob :)

I'm trying to play with Facebook flux todolist tutorial(flux-todomvc). I want to run an http server on my localhost port 8000 and usually I do that by running a script in the json.package file that looks like this:

"start": "http-server -a localhost -p 8000"

The problem is that the package.json file that comes from the source has this:

"start": "watchify -o js/bundle.js -v -d js/app.js"

So if I call "nmp start" it calls the above and obviously no server starts up. I don't know how to edit the package.json so that I can run the server.

I tried making a custom "script" attribute to call but that didn't work. How do I edit that package.json file, or is it intended that I server up this application a different way?

Answer (score 1):

It just builds app. Since this is pure client side just open index.html and you will be able to run sample.